# Dynamically Changing Video Source Causes Flicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have native video tag with source which dynamically changes by onEnded event which triggers a method that loads in the next video source in the tag for playback.

The main implementation is to make a playlist and keep inject the video sources until reached the end of the list.

** PROBLEM: As soon as the video source changes, it flickers for a few milliseconds and then plays the next video.

- Have tried multiple approaches to solve including fixed width - height but didn't work.
- Once approach was to render multiple players and turn them hide/show depending on which source is being play. This approach worked as expected but the drawback was that if I had 100 videos in the playlist, it would add 100 video nodes in the DOM.

I am sure that it is not a page re-render & there are no other props or state changes other than video source.

Have even tried implementing redux to handle it with global state but no luck!

Attached a video link showing the problem:
[See Video](https://ntvlivestream.com/video-flicker.mov)

Answer (score 0):

I'm impressed that it's as smooth as it's appearing.  A lot of context is torn down and set up again when you change the `src`.

> Once approach was to render multiple players and turn them hide/show depending on which source is being play. This approach worked as expected but the drawback was that if I had 100 videos in the playlist, it would add 100 video nodes in the DOM.

You don't need 100... you just need 2.  Get your next player ready to transition to, while the first one is finishing.  Once you've transitioned, destroy the first player and get the third ready.